# Is a grid possible with elements representing rows in CSS?

Tags: css, html-table, css-grid

I'm trying to replicate this design using HTML/CSS for modern browser:

[image]

It's essentially a table, with rows and columns, that means if the name cell for a row becomes bigger, it should become bigger for all of them. I see two possibilities: tables and CSS grid.

Rows in tables, as far as I can see, are not stylable enough, they can't take a border radius for example, I haven't tried box shadow.

If I use a CSS grid, I can style the cells to simulate border radius at the end, but then the box shadow becomes impossible because the box shadow of the second cell covers the first one.

I think the problem boils down to having elements that represent rows for styling but still inside each of them, the cells should be the same width as in the other rows, to represent columns.

Is there any way in CSS to achieve this?

For example, here's an attempt to do it with HTML's `table` in which the margin and border radius have no effect:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Eva Lee</td>
    <td>Call back</td>
    <td>15/02/19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Evelyn Allen</td>
    <td>Call back</td>
    <td>14/01/19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Slawomir Pelikan</td>
    <td>Voicemail</td>
    <td>14/01/19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Christopher Walken</td>
    <td>Voicemail</td>
    <td>14/01/19</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's another attempt, using `display: table`, which acts the same as `table`:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Eva Lee</div>
    <div class="cell">Call back</div>
    <div class="cell">15/02/19</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Evelyn Allen</div>
    <div class="cell">Call back</div>
    <div class="cell">14/01/19</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Slawomir Pelikan</div>
    <div class="cell">Voicemail</div>
    <div class="cell">14/01/19</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Christopher Walken</div>
    <div class="cell">Voicemail</div>
    <div class="cell">14/01/19</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `display:table` and you will avoid table and still be able to have the table layout with the styles you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I think that has the same shortcomings as the table. I updated the question to include examples.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the needed styles

Answer (score 1):

### Edit 1

This works in FF, Chrome, MSIE, MS Edge.
The Edge might need a little tweaking, as the table cells have sub pixel width, if now pixel width is give, leading to annoying vertical bars.

This works through using negative margins on `div`s which wrap the cells content and `overflow: hidden` on the cells.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
table tr td {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
table tr td > div {
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
}
table tr td:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
table tr td:first-child > div {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
table tr td:last-child {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
table tr td:last-child > div {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem.</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Ea!</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Animi.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Quas!</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Dolor!</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Suscipit.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Mollitia?</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Inventore!</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Dolorem.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Old, not working in Chrome

How about a little pseudo-element magic?

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}
tr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gold;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Eva Lee</td>
    <td>Call back</td>
    <td>15/02/19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Evelyn Allen</td>
    <td>Call back</td>
    <td>14/01/19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Slawomir Pelikan</td>
    <td>Voicemail</td>
    <td>14/01/19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Christopher Walken</td>
    <td>Voicemail</td>
    <td>14/01/19</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When I run the code snippet, the output doesn't look like the design I posted.

Comment: I'm not going to replicate your design. I only gave you a hint how to manage the border radius and shadow issues.

Comment: Yeah, but you are applying a border radius to a table, that works. The problem is applying a border radius and a box shadow to a tr.

Comment: Please look again. I apply the border radius Nd shadow to a pseudo element which is positioned absolutely inside the relative `tr`

Comment: you are testing you code using FF, I guess. pseudo element on `tr` don't work on Chrome (don't know about the other browser) but as far as I know they aren't supposed to work on tr .. that's why I used them on td within my answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are absolutely right. Didn't test it in Chrome. I assumed it to work there. If this method doesn't work, I can't come up with a different solution.

Comment: @pupeno I made an edit and new approach in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome the styling issue with some trick. Here is an example where I rely on pseudo element to style a row:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cell span {
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

.cell:first-child {
  padding: 10px 5px 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

.cell:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.cell:first-child:before {
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 6px;
}

.cell:last-child:before {
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 6px;
}

.cell:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cell:nth-child(2):before {
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px;
}

.cell:nth-child(2):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 11px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(green,green) left 5px top 50%/ 2px 80% no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(green,green) right 5px top 50%/ 2px 80% no-repeat,
  #fff;
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Eva Lee</div>
    <div class="cell"><span>Call back</span></div>
    <div class="cell">15/02/19</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Evelyn Allen</div>
    <div class="cell"><span>Call back back</span></div>
    <div class="cell">14/01/2019</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Slawomir Pelikan</div>
    <div class="cell"><span>Voicemail</span></div>
    <div class="cell">14/01/19</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Christopher Walken</div>
    <div class="cell"><span>Voicemail Voicemail</span></div>
    <div class="cell">14/01/19</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you integrate box-shadow into this?

Comment: @yunzen check the update, a shadow on all the sides ;)

Comment: While this is technically a shadow, it appears more like an outer glow. What about drop shadows like this: `box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);`?

Comment: @yunzen well, it can be adjusted as needed, I made in all the side to show it possible, we can then easily translate it

Answer (score 0):

## Grids rows with box shadow

To fix the box-shadow instead of creating one grid with elements.
I create one grid for each row.
This was lets us create the rows size function.
While still holding getting the one row elements to apply a box shadow onto.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 150px 200px;
  width: 100%;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #222; */
  margin: 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #222;
}

.name {}

.status {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}

.status:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 2px solid #aaa;
  height: calc(1em + 20px);
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
}

.status:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 2px solid #aaa;
  height: calc(1em + 20px);
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
}

.decoration {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.decoration.error {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.date {
  text-align: center;
}

.container .row div {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container .row div:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.container .row div:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      Lee Wong
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <span class="decoration error">
      error
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      12/5/2020
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      Lee Wong
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <span class="decoration error">
      error
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      12/5/2020
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      Lee Wong
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <span class="decoration error">
      error
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      12/5/2020
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Note. While this works as intended, it only works, if there is only one no no `auto` column per row.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qe8367o1/ You can have multiple auto columns. But your markup has to match the given css. Its possible to setup the grid with area names to work around that.

Comment: If you want text indepentent size use `1fr 1fr 150px 200px` instead of `auto auto 150px 200px`.